# Excel add-in takes a long time to save

Tags: excel, save, vba

I'm working on an Excel/VB add-in.  The .xla is about 3.11 MB.  The problem I'm seeing is when I save the project, it takes considerably longer than I would expect.  Is this normal behavior, or is there a fix for this issue?

Comment: This issue appears to have been addressed on http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/VB_Script/Q_22784042.html However I don't have access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that this cannot be fixed.  Looks like I'll have to deal with it.